# Which Pokemon have a special animation when running with them out of their pokeball?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

When selected to be let out of their pokeball, most Pokemon will simply run beside you. However, I've noticed that some have special animations. e.g. You can ride on the back of Charizard and Haunter as they fly, you grip onto Snorlax's belly and your movement basically controls him stomping around.

Is there a list of Pokemon that have these special animations when out of their pokeballs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the list is short, the following are the Pokémon that are rideable or have different animations while outside their pokeball. If you want to see all animations, [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlHxzu9vk_Y) has a video that shows them all.

**Land**

- Rideable, with faster traveling speeds: **Rapidash, Tauros, Arcanine, Persian**
- Rideable, with moderate traveling speeds: **Starmie, Rhyhorn, Rhydon, Machamp, Dodrio**
- Rideable, with slower traveling speeds: **Haunter, Snorlax, Kangaskhan, Onix**
- Not rideable, but will run in front of you: **Rattata, non-starter Pikachu, Mankey, Magikarp, Krabby, Mew**

**Sea**

- Only ridable while surfing: **Lapras, Gyarados**

**Sky**

- Only ridable after defeating the elite four: **Charizard, Dragonite, Aerodactyl**

**Sources**

1. [Polygon](https://www.polygon.com/pokemon/2018/11/27/18112514/pokemon-lets-go-rideable-pokemon)
2. [Gamewith](https://gamewith.net/pokemon-lets-go/article/show/1931)
3. [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonLetsGo/comments/9y0um9/mankey_acts_like_a_bodyguard/) and comments by Mike.C.Ford/Kimberly W

Comment: Actually, the flying Pokemon can be ridden prior to defeating the Elite 4. In most cases, they'll just fly close to the ground, except for Pokemon Road, where the high winds allows them to fly in the sky as if you were the Champion. Riding Charizard prior to being able to fly is still a really fast mode of travel and recommended if you're just passing through and don't want to have to add another fire or normal type to your team.